# Functioning of battery banks for GoPro 4 Silver

Tags: action-cam

I was disappointed with the short duration of the standard battery in my GoPro.

I would like to be able to shoot for a full day, without interruption. I researched external battery power banks, but I am confused. Does the powerbank 'override' the battery, allowing for continuous shooting, or does it only re-charge the battery, then switch off? (which seems to be implied in some posts)

Is there an alternative to the power bank?

Appreciate any advice.